# Laravel Ajax call deletes session flash data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

My repeated Ajax call deletes session flash data

I have a Javascript to make an Ajax call it calls my api every 5 seconds to update my user page.

I am returning a view with flash data which it has to keep for the next request but the Ajax call clears it and the next request is not completed.

Is there a way to complete it?

I can think to re-flash on an api call, but that seems weird. Any other way?

Comment: Does your ajax call need session information?

Comment: Yes. It needs session information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your ajax call needs access to the session information, you have to load the session, which will count as your access to the flash data. You will need your ajax call to reflash the data.

There is a `reflash` method on the session that will take care of this for you. You can either call it in the Controller method that handles your ajax call, or better yet, create a new middleware that reflashes session data, and attach the middleware to any route that needs this functionality.